# Trouble finding solution in 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve and get the general solution of the differential equation $y''-2y'+2y=x e^{x}\cos{2x}+e^x \sin{2x}+xe^x \sin{x}$ and I think that in order to get the particular solution it can be solved by the undetermined coefficients but it is very long, is there any other method or trick?

Comment: I believe undetermined coefficients is the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

What I should have done first is to let $y=z\,e^x$ to make the equation
$$y''-2y'+2y=x e^{x}\cos{(2x)}+e^x \sin{(2x)}+xe^x \sin{(x)}$$ to become
$$z''+z=x \cos{(2x)}+ \sin{(2x)}+x \sin{(x)}$$ which is more pleasant and easier to work  using undetermined coefficients.

Comment: can you explain why this change work like that with the equation?